# How to show ASP.NET default yellow screen of death, with debug info such as file paths, but without the source error section

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I have an application here, that is configured for release, and has debug disabled in the compilation settings, yet with default ASP.NET yellow screen of death it shows source error.

[My HttpApplication configured with debug disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozkVk.png)

Now I want this page to be preserved (I want the default exception page without turning customErrors on.)
And I want paths to be preserved also, but I don't want it to render the Source Error section, like this:

[Example of paths in exception but no source error section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF4Sq.png)

(Notice the way that the source error says `An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`, it can also show information regarding the compilation settings)

The one solution I have tried is via removing PDBs, but I still want the assembly paths.

Any more information on this, or any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

IIS 10.0, .NET Framework 4.0.30319 and ASP.NET 4.8.4330.0

- Nikita

Comment: It's a debug screen for developing.  It's designed as an all or nothing.  For debugging there is no reason to turn it off.  For production there is no reason to have it on.  But generally speaking, it not something you can configure either.

Comment: you could just write your own error pages which might give a better experience :)

Comment: @DanielA.White true I could write my own, but I thought that this would have been something that would've been built into ASP.NET

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Why would you want to voluntarily leak details of your application and provide a degraded user experience? As Erik mentioned, it was designed this way because those details are only useful to developers, not end users. All the end user needs to know is something went wrong.

Comment: Yeah I have figured out why it does this at times, it will look for the files on the current machine, and it if finds them it will echo back where the error originated in the code. If it doesn't find it, it will just echo back `
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`